# Alteration of variable value in C

Tags: c

[UPDATE]: The answer by Keine Lust, to explicitly declare the size of array solves the problem.

I am trying to write my own decimal to binary converter in C (posted below), which constantly is giving wrong outputs due to alteration of value of variable named a. Why is the alteration happening? And the compiler I'm using is gcc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void) {
 int j = 0; // This variable is used to counter the iterations of while-loop
 int a; // This variable holds user-input
 char b[] = {}; // This is character array to hold the value of bits after operation
 printf("Enter a number to convert into binary\n>>>");
 scanf("%d", &a); 
 while(a!=0){ // Loop until the value of a is 0
  printf("a before modulus: %d \n", a); // printing a for debugging
  int bit = a % 2; // represents binary digit
  printf("a after modulus:%d \n", a); // print a for debugging
  switch(bit){ // switch-case to identify the bit
   case 1:
    b[j] = '1'; 
    break;
   case 0:
    b[j] = '0';
    break; 
  }
    printf("a after switch-case:%d \n", a); // the value of a is altered after switch-case, check output.
    a = (int) floor((float)(a/2));  
    j += 1;
 }
printf("\n");
  return 0; 
}
```

## OUTPUT: (*input*: 2)

a before modulus:2

a after modulus:2

a after switch-case:48

a before modulus: 24

a after modulus:24

a after switch-case:12312

a before modulus: 6156

a after modulus:6156

..... continues

**COMPLETED CODE THAT WORKS:** [UPDATE]

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <math.h>
    int main(void) {
    const int MAX_SIZE = sizeof(char) * 10000; // Will hold 10000 characters
        int j = 0; // This variable is used to counter the iterations of while-loop
        int a,temp; // This variable holds user-input
        char b[MAX_SIZE]; // This is character array to hold the value of bits after operation will hol
        printf("Enter a number to convert into binary\n>>>");
        scanf("%d", &a);
        temp = a; 
        int bits = log(a)/log(2);
        bits += 1;
        while(a!=0){ // Loop until the value of a is 0

          int bit = a % 2; // represents binary digit

       switch(bit){ // switch-case to identify the bit
        case 1:
            b[j] = '1'; 
            break;
        case 0:
            b[j] = '0';
            break; 
       }
            a = a/2;    
            j += 1;
      }
        printf("The %d in binary is: ",temp);
      for (int c=(bits-1);c>=0;c--) {
        printf("%c", b[c]); 
      }
        printf("\n");
       return 0; 
     }
```

Comment: `char b[] = {};` is not legal, switch to `char b[MAX_ELEMENTS];` where `MAX_ELEMENTS` could be `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT`

Comment: How many characters do you think this variable `char b[] = {};` provides?

Comment: This might be a matter of preferences and opinion, but I think indenting by more than one letter would match the reading habits of many people.

Comment: Doesn't the compiler warn you about this `char b[] = {};`?

Comment: @alk No it doesn't warn me.

Comment: That solves the problem @KeineLust. Thanks!

Comment: @n00b: You are welcome, but your compiler should trigger an error: `error: zero or negative size array ‘b’`
`

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @KeineLust But it doesn't.

Comment: @alk GCC on debian.

Comment: For GCC, you might like to use the options `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` at least. `-Wconversion` also is a good one.

Comment: To learn what is going on do a `printf("size of b = %zu bytes\n", sizeof b);`.

Comment: Please note that a/2, beeing a an int, is already an integer division that will drop the reminder. Casting and rounding its result is useless.

Comment: print a after `a = (int) floor((float)(a/2));` with an odd value of a like 3 or 5 and see